# automatically retrieve data from related tables

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a database that contains a table called `model_meta` which contains metadata about all the various models in use by the application. Here is the relevant data structure:

```
CREATE TABLE model_meta (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(64),
  oo INT(11),
  om INT(11),
  mo INT(11),
  mm INT(11),
  INDEX (name)
);

CREATE TABLE inventory (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  type VARCHAR(255),
  customers_id INT(11)
);

CREATE TABLE customers (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  contact VARCHAR(255)
);
```

The columns `oo`, `om`, `mo`, and `mm` in the `model_meta` table contain a comma-separated list of ids to which that model has the specified relationship (i.e. one-to-one, one-to-many, etc.).

When a client requests data, all I'm given is the name of the table they're requesting (e.g. 'inventory') - from that, I need to determine what relationships exist and query those tables to return the appropriate result set.

Given a single variable (let's call it `$input`) that contains the name of the requested model, here are the steps:

1. get model metadata: `SELECT model_meta.* FROM model_meta WHERE model_meta.name = $input;`
2. determine which, if any, of the relationship columns (oo, om, mo, mm) contain values - keeping in mind that they can contain a comma-separated list of values.
3. use the values from step 2 to determine the name of the related model(s) - for the sake of example, let's just say that only `mo` contains a value and we'll refer to it as `$mo`.

   So: `SELECT model_meta.name FROM model_meta WHERE model_meta.id = $mo;`

   Let's call this result `$related`.
4. Finally, select data from the requested table and all tables that are related to it - keeping in mind that we may be dealing with a one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, or many-to-many relationship. For this specific example:

   In psuedo-SQL: `SELECT $input.*, $related.* FROM $input LEFT JOIN $related ON ($related.id = $input.$related_id);`

This method uses three separate queries - the first to gather metadata about the requested table, the second to gather the names of related tables, and the third to query those tables and return the actual data.

**My question:** Is there an elegant way to combine any of these queries, reducing their number from from 3 to 2 - or even down to one single query?

The real goal, of course, is to in some way automate the retrieval of data from related tables (without the client having to knowing *how* the tables are related). That's the goal.

Comment: See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Comment: @eggyal Ah, fair enough - thanks for the link! But, for the sake of me learning new things, let's assume that the oo, om, mo, and mm columns can only contain a single value...